# Is It OK to Delete Original Repo After Migration to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, bitbucket

I have Migrated a few of my Projects from BitBucket to Gitlab.
I just wanted to check the GitLab.com, with some projects and various features it provides.

I want to permanently migrate a few of my projects from BitBucket Repo to the GitLab.com.
I have done the import of projects to Gitlab.

**But I have a few queries here**:

1. I see the "Leave Project" link of the Repositories migrated from BitBucket, rather I don't see this "Leave Project" link on other repositories, which are directly created on GitLab. Which means, does GitLab is still connected with BitBucket for Repo?
2. What will happen if I delete the original BitBucket Repo? Will the new Project repository I have imported will work / or will not work?
3. I have read about the migration of projects from BitBucket to GitLab.com, but in those docs, it's not mentioned that it is OK to delete the original repo.

I need help on these questions so that I can move some of my projects fully on GitLab and remove the repositories (which I have migrated to GitLab already) from BitBucket.

Thank you.

Comment: is this bitbucket cloud or stash?

Comment: BitBucket Cloud I think, from bitbucket.org website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. "Leave Project"

So it looks like when you import your Project from BitBucket to GitLab, it will create a Project for you on Gitlab

> Leave a project
>   Leave project will only display on the project’s dashboard when a project is part of a group (under a group namespace). If you choose to leave a project you will no longer be a project member, therefore, unable to contribute.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/#leave-a-project

To answer your question about GitLab still having links to the original repo: Nope, it clones the original Repo.

---

### 2. Deleting Original BitBucket Repo

Deleting the original repo will not have an effect on code already imported or code pushed after the import to your gitlab repository. The newly created Repository is a clone of the original one.

---

### 3. Documentation regarding Deleting Original

I too have looked and could not find anything of substance, but I can tell you that i have personally performed this process, and not just with BitBucket, but with GitLab as well, and have not had any issues in this regard.

Hope this helps!
Good Luck :)

Comment: Sure. Thank you, @Craig Wayne.
I will give it a go and will post the results in the comments.

Comment: Thanks. It worked well.
I just updated the remote URL for the workspace, from where I was doing my local development, and also deleted the BitBucket URL as a remote and BitBucket Repository from Cloud.
I can commit normally to the new repo now, and it is working fine.
One more good thing is, because of this migration, I could also maintain the history of commits.
This is fantastic.

Comment: I had query for reverse approach. I  imported a project from labcase git repo to gitlab for test purpose and now I want to delete the project in gitlab . So I wanted to know if deleting the imported project in gitlab will have any effect on original source i.e my labcase repo.